# Shiny module synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread

Tags: javascript, datatables, shiny, rstudio

I'm working on a Shiny module and generating data table using Javascript code through Ajax. But when the module is used in a Shiny app, Chrome keeps saying there is synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread and I can't figure out why.
The module ui is generated by Javascript code which has a data table listing some data objects retrieved by Ajax call to a local desktop application's RESTful API. There is two buttons in the UI, one is 'Refresh', when it is clicked, ajax.reload() gets called while the other one is an 'Import' button which will import the selected row into the Shiny app.

I'm assuming the issue is not caused by the 'Import' button because when the page loads, the warning message shows up immediately, the 'Import' button didn't get clicked and plus the importing process is explicitly specified to use an async call. So the issue is caused by the initial ajax call that initializes the data table but I think it should default use a async call as well.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
wrapWithDocumentReady <- function(jsCode) {
  return(paste0("$(document).ready(function(){", jsCode, "});"))
}

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  jsCode <- paste0(
    # 1st to initialize the data table
    "let objectTable = $('#",
    ns("dataObjectTable"),
    "').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
    url: 'http://localhost:XXXX/some_application/data',
    dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
    { name: 'name', data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
    { name: 'data_type', data: 'data_type', title: 'Data Type', visible:false },
    { name: 'id', data: 'id', title: 'ID', visible: false },
    { name: 'dimension', data: 'dimension', title: 'Dimension'},
    ],
    select: {
    style: 'single'
    },
} );",

    # 2nd to bind the 'Import' button with event
    "$('#",
    ns("importButton"),
    "').click(function() {",
    "
    let selectedDataId = objectTable.cell('.selected', 'id:name').data();

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost:XXXX/some_application/data/'.concat(selectedDataId);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
    var dataJson = this.responseText;
    Shiny.onInputChange('", ns("addDataObject"),"', dataJson);
    }
    }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    });",

    # 3rd to bind the 'Reresh' button with event
    "$('#",
    ns("refreshButton"),
    "').click(function() { 
    objectTable.ajax.reload();
    });"
    );

  tagList(
    div(tags$table(id = ns("dataObjectTable"), width="100%")),
    actionButton(ns("refreshButton"), "Refresh"),
    actionButton(ns("importButton"), "Import"),

    tags$script(wrapWithDocumentReady(jsCode))
  )
  }

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {

  importedData <- reactive ({
    jsonStr <- input$addDataObject
    if (!is.null(jsonStr)) {
      # passing the data and return
    } else {NULL}

  })

  return(importedData)
}
```